# Page will only display first 6 videos

Tags: videos, performance, video-player

I'm creating a page in WordPress using a custom theme. I have a page that I need to put 8 (maybe more) videos on. With 6 video players on the page it loads in less than a second, but as soon as I put any more videos on, it just loads the first 6 videos then the page continues to load for ages. In the bottom left corner of Chrome it says "Processing Request". I don't understand why 1 or 2 more videos would prevent the page from loading properly.

This page contains videos that will introduce you to the different IT & business systems that we use in the company. This includes Google Apps, Dropbox, WorkflowMax, Skype and TeamGantt.

```
<div class="video">
<h3>Gmail</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Using-Gmail.mp4"][/video]

</div>
<div class="video">
<h3>Google Calendar</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Google-Calendar.mp4"][/video]

</div>
<div class="video">
<h3>Dropbox</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Using-Dropbox.mp4"][/video]

</div>
<div class="video">
<h3>Team Gantt</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Team-Gantt.mp4"][/video]

</div>
<div class="video">
<h3>Skype</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Using-Skype.mp4"][/video]

</div>
<div class="video">
<h3>WorkflowMax Introduction</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/WFM-Introduction.mp4"][/video]

</div>
<div class="video">
<h3>WorkflowMax - Purchase Orders</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/WFM-Purchase-Orders.mp4"][/video]

</div>
<div class="video">
<h3>WorkflowMax - Timesheets and logging time</h3>
[video mp4="http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/WFM-Time-Sheets.mp4"][/video]

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post you page code? Also you can increase post_per_page limit to 8 in your query

Comment: I have entered the above code into the the main content box of the WordPress page editor

Comment: I have tried with upto 9 videos, it was working fine. But when i increased it to 10, it has start giving problem in loading. Its the issue regarding the video size which takes time to load.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's to do with the size of the videos, because I tried switching them all around and it just only loads the first 6 videos, regardless of the size

Comment: I put your code in page and it loads as many videos i wanna load.

Comment: Interesting - Was that a WordPress site or just HTML. I've tried both but neither worked. I also tried changing themes and disabling all plugins, but to no avail.